# Run loop array in order

Tags: arrays, angular, loops

I am trying to run satellite image animation with buttons controls .l have array of dates satellite image animation.

```
  ["20200922", "20200923", "20200924", "20200925", "20200926", "20200927", "20200928"]
```

My code below is working fine . But when i run the code i have random output array , is not running  as orderly

Code :

```
 saturation: number = 1000
  timeStops: any[];
  imgs:any[]
  _index :number = 0;
  index: number = 0;
  date$: Observable<any>;
  image$: Observable<any>;
  datepush: any[][];
  datearray:any[]


      play() {
    
        const now = moment()
    
        this.timeStops = [];
        this.datearray = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    
          now.subtract(15, 'minutes')
          this.timeStops.push(this.roundTimeQuarterHour(now).utc().format('YYYYMMDD'));
    
          this.imgs= [
            new Image().src = "" + this.timeStops[10] + "T000000/time/00/image",
            new Image().src = "" + this.timeStops[9] + "T000000/time/24/image",
            new Image().src = "" + this.timeStops[8] + "T000000/time/48/image",
            new Image().src = "" + this.timeStops[7] + "T000000/time/72/image",
            new Image().src = "" + this.timeStops[6] + "T000000/time/96/image",
            new Image().src = "" + this.timeStops[5] + "T000000/time/120/image",
            new Image().src = "" + this.timeStops[4] + "T000000/time/144/image",
            new Image().src = "" + this.timeStops[3] + "T000000/time/168/image",
            new Image().src = "" + this.timeStops[2] + "T000000/time/192/image",
            new Image().src = "" + this.timeStops[1] + "T000000/time/216/image",
            new Image().src = "" + this.timeStops[0] + "T000000/time/240/image",
          ];
          }
          this.imgs.sort()
          this.datearray.sort()
          console.log(this.imgs)

          var fortnightStart = moment();
          for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
              // 1, not i
              this.datearray.push(fortnightStart.add(1, "days").format("YYYYMMDD"));
          }

          console.log(this.datearray);  
    
        console.log(this.index)
    

        if (Math.abs(this._index) < this.imgs.length &&Math.abs(this._index) < this.datearray.length) {
          this._index = this.imgs.length;
          this._index = this.datearray.length;
        }
        this.image$ = interval(this.saturation).pipe(
          map(() => {
            return this.imgs[this.calculateIndex()];
          }),
          startWith(this.imgs[10])
        );
        this.date$ = interval(this.saturation).pipe(
          map(() => {
            return this.datearray[this.calculateIndex()];
          }),
          startWith(this.datearray[0])
        );
      }
    
    
      calculateIndex(): number {
        if (Math.abs(this._index) >= this.imgs.length * 3 &&Math.abs(this._index) >= this.datearray.length * 3) {
          this._index = this._index % this.imgs.length;
          this._index = this._index % this.datearray.length;
        }
        if (this.stoploop) {
          this.index = this._index % this.imgs.length
          this.index = this._index % this.datearray.length
          return this.index;
        } else {
          if (this.isBackward) {
            this.index = Math.abs(--this._index % this.imgs.length);
            this.index = Math.abs(--this._index % this.datearray.length);
            return this.index;
          } else {
            this.index = (++this._index % this.imgs.length);
            this.index = (++this._index % this.datearray.length);
            return this.index;
          }
        }
      }
```

the output :

[image: gif output]

There is any way i can make the output loop as orderly ?

[Live code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-moment-example-osewsl?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: Please add the code that is causing the problem (the interval).

Comment: Your posted code would create an array in order. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: i update my code above . @mplungjan

Comment: @trincot i have updated

Comment: Please add your interval function. Best would be to create a stackblitz project, so that we can execute your code and reproduce your issue. You can add your code in the link here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ukfr5q

Comment: @حاجهب1000
You did not specify which language or framework you are using. It not pure JS, looks like Typescript/Angular.

Comment: @Nesar l am try to put my code on stackblitz but i have a lot of dependence missing

Comment: @Nesar https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-moment-example-osewsl?file=app/app.component.html check out pls

Comment: what's the purpose of caculateIndex function

Comment: for buttons control like forward or back @Nesar

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-moment-example-rn8ryz?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

does this help with your problem?

Comment: @Nesar . Thank you very much . appreciate . you solved it my problem , but i have 3 buttons are not working . first one is <<<< and sec one is >>>> alse 1+ and -1 . only play and stop button are working .

Comment: All buttons working now, <<<< will continue animation but backwards, >>>> will continue forward. 1+, 1- will stop animation, and show next and previous image receptively

Comment: <<<< and >>>> still now working !! @Nesar

Comment: what is the expected behavior for these two buttons?

Comment: <<<< get first image and >>> will get last image

Comment: i've modified the code. it will jump to first/last depending on the button you click (<<<<,>>>>) and continue animation. If you want to stop the animation, just call this.stop()

Comment: @Nesar beautiful . its look like i will remove `this.saturation` from `setInterval`  , because when i change the speed of `this.saturation` from the slider of speed i will get mess `setInterval`  . I dont know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script randomizing the index, checkout [I've modified your code.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-moment-example-rn8ryz?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
    startAnimation(){
    this.timeOutSubsription = setInterval(()=>{
      console.log(this.index)
      if(this.isBackward){
        this.index--;
        if(this.index<0){
          this.index = this._index;
        }
      } else{
        this.index++;
        if(this.index>this._index){
          this.index = 0;
        }
      }
      this.image$.next(this.imgs[this.index])
      this.date$.next(this.datearray[this.index])
    }, this.saturation);
  }
```

Hope this solves your issue.